# JQuery code working only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

What's wrong with this code?

```
$(function size() {
    var width = document.width;
    $('.section').css('width', 2 * width);
    $('body').css('width', 8 * width).css('font-size', 0.023 * width);
    $('.center').css('width', width);
    $('#title').css('width', 0.78 * width);
    $('#lf').css('width', 0.56 * width);
});

$(window).ready(size);
```

Please help! I've got no idea what is wrong :/

Comment: You'll need to tell us what's wrong. What error do you get and what is it not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of browser quirks!  Now, could you explain to us what you're trying to accomplish with this function?

Comment: `what's wrong with this code` is not a question when no other symptoms are provided

Comment: @charlietfl, but... `what's wrong with this code?` is a question! you omitted his question mark!

Comment: @gdoron  I also appended comment ...and could say `technical question` or `valid question`

Comment: Sorry - it has to resize some parts of my webside. It's getting a object document width and next resize other parts. It's only on page load. And this code working only in Chrome - there is no errors in other browsers.

Here is site:
http://podziemie.liveform.pl/

Comment: @charlietfl, you do know I was just teasing you, right...?

Comment: @gdoron  ... figured so... but you were right in English 101 terms!  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.width` is marked obsolete in MDN, use `document.body.clientWidth` instead.

Also isn't the `$(window).ready(...)` is not valid jquery, do you mean `$(window).load()`?

although as the first block of code is registering a handler in the same way as `$(document).ready(...)` would, then the second call is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var width = $(document).width();
```

instead of

```
var width = document.width;
```

In Chrome `var width = document.width;` returns the width but `undefined` in other browsers. Since you are using `jQuery` so take advantage of it. Also you can use your code like

```
function size() {
    var width = $(document).width();
    alert(width);
};
$(size); // calls ready event event
```